# How to make hollywood.cls available?

Tags: lyx, texlive, unix

I attempted to create a document of class "hollywood", and was warned by LyX, that the class is not available -- and needs to be installed.

When I try to preview the document, I get a LaTeX-error:

```
File `hollywood.cls' not found.
```

Yet, the file is installed with LyX -- under `/usr/local/share/lyx/tex`... I tried symlinking it into `/usr/local/share/texmf-local` (followed by `texhash`), but that didn't help.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I only can show you on windows, where I changed class via Document/Settings:

[image: document-settings]

On my system it's found in two places, don't know, which one Lyx is using:

[image: hollywood]

Closest match seems to be here, Tools/Preferences:
[image]

**P.S.**
Lyx operates on Linux exactly as I showed for Windows in the screenshot.

hollywood.cls resides under

```
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lyx
```

which, I suspect, is the standard place for the texmf tree. If your distribution installs it somewhere else, your system usually knows about it. If it doesn‘t, perhaps reviewing your installation process helps. Check for texmf on the web.

BTW, you can also check availability and pathes via Tools/Tex information.

With Latex the compiler also checks the current workdirectory of the document. So if for some reason you don‘t want to use texmf, copying a foreign class there works. Perhaps this bypass also works with Lyx.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help me -- with TexLive on Unix, rather than MikTex on Windows...

Comment: How do these dialogues look on your system, especially the pathes?

Comment: The two classes (Hollywood and Broadway) are marked "Unavailable". The "Document templates" path is, predictably, set to `/usr/local/share/lyx/templates`.

Comment: Kindly check my PS. Bye.

Comment: On Ubuntu I have:

$ apt-file find hollywood.cls
lyx-common: /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lyx/hollywood.cls